# C++ cast template type

Tags: c++

Consider the following code snippet :

```
[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const BasicIterator<const Type>& rhs) const noexcept {
    if( this == &rhs ) {
        return true;
    }
    return node_ == rhs.node_;
}

[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const BasicIterator<Type>& rhs) const noexcept {
    // how to call existing operator== implementation ??
    //return operator==( rhs );
}
```

How should I use the same implementation for both `operator==`? Is it possible to call `operator== <const Type>` version from `operator== <Type>`?

Is there any cast for template types in this case?

Comment: You can just remove the `const Type` overload as the `Type` overload can absorb the `const` in the template. For example `Type` can be `const int` in the second overload, so there is no need to specify the first if the implementation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Type` a template? If not, maybe make it a template?

```
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const BasicIterator<T>& rhs) const noexcept {
    if( this == &rhs ) {
        return true;
    }
    return node_ == rhs.node_;
}
```

If you do not want to expose this template to users, hide it somewhere and use in implementation:

```
private: 
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const BasicIterator<T>& lhs, const BasicIterator<T>& rhs) const noexcept {
    if( &lhs== &rhs ) {
        return true;
    }
    return lhs.node_ == rhs.node_;
}

public:
[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const BasicIterator<const Type>& rhs) const noexcept {
    return operator==<const Type>(*this, rhs);
}

[[nodiscard]] bool operator==(const BasicIterator<Type>& rhs) const noexcept {
    return operator==<Type>(*this, rhs);
}
```

Comment: Did anyone manage to make it work? I am getting `cannot be overloaded` error when both public functions there. But works fine with only one of them. I also tried to rename private one to "equals".

Comment: missing `friend` for private `operator==`.